# Setting a manual FolderPath to a MAPIFolder? C#

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I have been googling a lot but can't find anything how to solve this.

I have an Outlook Addin which import mails when a button is clicked. When the button is clicked it reads the *current active* folder like this:
inboxFolder = app.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder;

Therefore, if the user wants to import the e-mails he needs to have that inbox active. However, now I want to implement a timer instead which imports the e-mails every X minutes automatically so I need to set the inbox folder manually (so that the user doesn't need to have that folder selected) but I can't find a way to do this.

First I though it was something like this:
inboxFolder.FolderPath  = @"\\Outlook Data File\Inbox";
but FolderPath is read-only.

I have read on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder_properties(v=office.14).aspx) but most of the properties only returns something or "Is not intended to be used".

If anyone can help me with this it would be highly appreciated.

Best regards,
Tomas

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the GetDefaultFolder method to set the folder you want.

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MAPIFolder oFolder = oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

Comment: Hi Sorceri, thanks for your answer.

In this case it wont work because this folder is not a default folder. The user has it's own Inbox folder and then he adds a "Support" mail and it's from that Inbox I want to import the e-mails.

Best regards,
Tomas